# Google Places API not returning suggestions based on location

Tags: android, location, google-places-api

When I search from the Google Places Autocomplete, it gives suggestions/predictions from all around the world. However I want to get suggestions based on user's location. I have tried to change my location manually in the emulator, but it still does not work. I think I may be lacking something in my code, but I don't know what. Please help.

Code:

My Dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
```

**FindLocation Activity**

```
public class FindLocation extends AppCompatActivity 
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_location);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();

        try {
            Intent intent =
                    new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                            .build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
                //Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                //Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        //refreshPlacesData();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

My Activity's XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.project_water.FindLocation">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, and thanks to Mahesh Gawhane and Patrick R for helping me. But in order to answer my question fully, I had to first get the user's current location in terms of Latitude and Longitude. I followed [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/) tutorial to get the user's location in terms of Lat and Lng (depending on what your application is, you can customise the code to your need).

Then, I had to input this Lat and Lng coordinates into a LatLngBounds object, of which, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32368196/8207511) tutorial to do so. Once I had the LatLngBounds object, I called the `setBoundsBias()` method into the Places Autocomplete, see guide [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete).

Now, the Places Autocomplete will give 'bias' suggestions based on a certain 'bounded' area around the user's location! By 'bias' I mean relative to places not within this 'bounded' area.

Answer (score 2):

Updated code:

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds( new LatLng(23.8036125,72.1932621), new LatLng(23.9365798,72.4171406));
        final AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                .build();
        try {

            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY).
                    setBoundsBias(bounds).
                    setFilter(typeFilter).build(LocationPickerActivityDEMO.this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The Google Places API Guides suggests that this Fragment should only be add if I want it to appear as a fragment. However, I am using intent to start autocomplete as an activity.

Comment: By enabling from Google Console, do you mean retrieving the API key? If so, I have already done that.

Comment: Thanks, but this works only for a specific location. I need it to work for the user's current location.

Comment: You just need to replace static coordinates with your user's current location.

Comment: wouldn't that be too much work to manually change the coordinates every time? Is there a way to programme the code such that the places autocomplete gives suggestions automatically based on useres location? @Patrick R

Answer (score 1):

Set LatLongBounds to PlaceAutoComplete for show result of user current location like

below line gives bounds of current location

```
    LatLngBounds bounds = mGoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
    Log.i("curScreen", ""+bounds);
```

or you can set static latlongbounds like

```
    LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds(
                new LatLng(19.8036125,75.1932621),
                new LatLng(19.9365798,75.4171406));
```

then set filter to Place Autocomplete

```
    final AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
            .setTypeFilter(3)
            .build();
```

and pass that `LatLongBounds` and `AutocompleteFilter` to `PlaceAutocomplete` Intent

```
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY).setBoundsBias(bounds).setFilter(typeFilter).build(MapActivity.this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

    }
```

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getProjection()' on a null object reference